# Can't browse interent with Ubuntu 18.04 , OpenVPN issue?

Tags: firefox, openvpn

I have two machines with installed:
Computer 1. Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Computer 2. Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Both are running the same iptables rules.
Both are connected to two different openvpn servers.

Computer 1. "disconnects" within a minute and i can't browse internet via either Firefox or chrome. But. I can browse via command line browsers.

Computer 2. never disconnects from openvpn server and i can always browse internet via either Firefox or CL.

i tried switching between servers but the problem persist.

What is the problem with Computer 1. ?

How can i troubleshoot this problem? Where to start?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**UPDATE: Presently, I can't browse internet via terminal (CL) anymore on 18.04. I can ssh to my openvpn servers but I can't browse internet !?**

Comment: Hi, could it be that Ubuntu 16 vs. 18 have different browser versions (perhabs ESR versions), or that their Ubuntu-specific configurations differ slightly. Looks as if Ubuntu 16.04 has a bug that 18.04 hasn't any more. Second idea (very different), can you just backup the complete images of your HDDs (of SSDs) and then swap them and try to boot them on the "wrong" computer? Maybe new insights are to be gained here? Regards, M.

Comment: Thanks Micha. Both machines have Mozilla Firefox 72.0.1
Also, both OSes are installed on a separate usb drive. I just switched them between computers but the problem still persist(16.04 has no problems. But. 18.04 "disconnects" within a minute??).

Comment: Hi, I need to be honest, at that point I'm not an expert on VPN connections. However, may I bring to your attention that it seems to me that Ubuntu with Firefox  is not alone, it seems to be a more general issue (searched "ubuntu vpn tunnel 60 seconds timeout" in DuckDuckGo, got 6 hits out of the first 10 results. Regards, M.